# changing data from printing line by line to a list (in a text file)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using python, idle version 3.4.2
My code when it prints, print 3 scores per name but they print like this:

```
Maya: 3
Maya:2
Maya: 4
```

I was wondering if there was any way to get it to print like this in a list/dictionary so i can call upon the scores later for sorting

```
Maya = [3,2,4]
```

Here is my code.

```
students_names = []
import random #import module
print("What is your name?") #prints writing in brackets
name = input().title() #Capitalizes the first letter of the word inputted
students_names.append(name)

print("What class are you in? (Enter 1, 2 or 3)") #asks the user to input a number

while True:
   try:
       class_number = int(input()) #asks for an integer input from user
   except ValueError: 
       print("Sorry, I didn't understand that, please try again") #print statement
       continue

   if class_number > 3: #if input is more than 3
       print("SORRY but that class isn't recognised, try again") #print statement
       continue
   else:
       print ("Hello,", name, "from class", class_number, "welcome to my quiz") #prints writing in brackets and anything saved in the variable "name" and "class_number"
       break #break out of loop

score = 0  #sets the variable "score" to zero
question = 0 # sets the variable "question" to zero
print(class_number)

while question < 3:#If questions (intitally set to 0) is smaller than 10, carry out this function
   question +=1 # add one to the value of "question"
   maths = random.randint(1,3) #randomly generate a number from 1-3 and store as "maths"
   num1 = random.randint(1,10)#randomly generate an integer from 1-10 and store as "num1"
   num2 = random.randint(1,10)#randomly generate a second integer from 1-10 and store as "num2"
   if maths == 1: #if the number generated is 1 
       print(num1, "+", num2) #prints num1 + num2
       ans = num1 + num2 #sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 added to num2

   elif maths == 2: #if the number generated is 1
       print(num1, "*", num2) #print num1 multiplied by num2
       ans = num1 * num2 #sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 multiplied by num2

   else: #else run this part of code
       print(num1, "-", num2) #print num1 subtracted by num2
       ans = num1 - num2 #sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 subtracted by num2

   while True:
       try:
           user_ans = int(input()) #user inputs answer to question
       except ValueError: #runs when the user input is no an integer
           print ("SORRY but that answer isn't recognised, try again")
       else:
           break


   if user_ans == ans:
       score+=1
       print("Well done, you are CORRECT")

   else:
       print("SORRY, you are INCORRECT") #print writing in brackets
       print("The correct answer was", ans)

if score == 10: #run this part of code if "score" equals 10
       print("fantastic", name, "you got full marks!")#print statement and name 
elif score >= 6: #run this part of code if "score" is larger than or equal to 6
       print("well done, there's some improvement to be done here though", name, "you got", score, "/10")# then print statement and score
elif score <=5: #run this part of code if "score" is smaller than or equal to 5
       print("hmm, maybe some more practise would be beneficial", name, "you got", score, "/10") #then print statement and score

class_number = str(class_number) + ".txt" #this adds '.txt' to the end of the file (therefore creating a text file) so it can be used to create a file under the name of the class
file = open(class_number, 'a') #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
file.write(str(students_names))
file.write(str(name + " : ")) #writes the name and ":" to file
file.write(str(score)) #writes the score to file
file.write('\n')#writes the score to the file
file.close()#safely closes the file to save the information
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code is a bit confusing me. The `updatedlines.append(line)` original indentation makes me believe there is an issue with the if/else, but reading the code, it looks like the issue is the indentation. Can you triple check your pasted code, please?

Comment: Also, can you give an example of the input file you're using, and what you want as output file, given the example input?

Comment: I have updated it, please could you have a look

Comment: The updatedlines code was recommended to me but it was saving in my text file like this ['Maya']Maya : 0
['Maya']Maya : 0
Maya : 0
['0\n', '0']  Which was very confusing

Comment: and BTW, welcome to stack overflow, please update your question with the details I'm asking, to help us help you achieve what you're asking for. A good idea would also be to make your code a [Minimal Concise Example](http://sscce.org) so we can focus on the algorithm or your issue, and not the context.

Answer (score 0):

Sure simply add the score values foreach person to a new dictionary.

```
name_dict = {}

if name in name_dict:
   name_dict[name].append(new_score)
else:
   name_dict[name] = [new_score]
```

*It is a little bit hard to follow up on your code. Therefore I was not completely able to integrate it.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get what you're looking for. But to simplify my answer to that, we first need to simplify your example. A good way to do so, is to cut your code into functions:

### How to store your results?

First we'll look at where you need help on, which is the last bit of your code, which fits in a function we'll call `store_results()`:

```
 def store_results(...):
      class_number = str(class_number) + ".txt" # this adds '.txt' to the end of the file (therefore creating a text file) so it can be used to create a file under the name of the class
      file = open(class_number, 'a') # opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
      file.write(str(students_names))
      file.write(str(name + " : ")) # writes the name and ":" to file
      file.write(str(score)) # writes the score to file
      file.write('\n') # writes the score to the file
      file.close() # safely closes the file to save the information
```

I used here `...` for the arguments of the function, which is not python, to have a thought about it. What arguments does that function needs to work as is?

- `class_number`: the class the student answering the QA is in
- `name`: the score the student had on the QA
- `student_names`

What you're doing here, is that when you run that code, you're appending `name`
into `student_names`, which will always contain one, and only one name. So when
you write `file.write(str(students_names))`, for a user whose name is `John`, you'll
end up writing:

```
...
['John']
John : 5
...
```

Which is not something I believe you're expecting. You actually do not need that list at all.

So as a first update, you should do:

```
 def store_results(class_number, name, score):
      class_file = "{}.txt".format(class_number)  # this adds '.txt' to the end of the file (therefore creating a text file) so it can be used to create a file under the name of the class
      with open(class_file, 'a') as f: # opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
           f.write("{}: {}\n".format(name, score) # outputs the user's score to the file
```

Other changes in that snippet are:
- you shall not use `file` as a variable as it already exists as a global type, and using it in
your code is considered bad practice called "shadowing" which can lead to hard to find bugs 
(not in this case, but if you don't take the good habits now, it's bite you in a future code).
- you shall use `with open() as f:` construct instead of opening and closing the file manually,
because in your existing code, if there's an exception thrown between `open` and `close` your
file won't be properly closed, ending up in possible lost writes.
- you shall use format strings instead of direct string concatenation, which makes the code
easier to read and to modify.

Now, that being said, you'll still have your issue having the result of each test taken
by an user being shown as:

```
John: 2
John: 4
John: 5
```

The right way to solve this is to not use "blinded" appending to the file, but instead
use the file as some sort of very basic database. The most simple option would be to
write your scores within a JSON file, which is syntactically compatible with python
(pretty useful for manual testing):

```
import os
import json

def store_results(class_number, name, score):
    # this adds '.json' to the end of the file (therefore creating a json file)
    class_file = "{}.json".format(class_number)

    # first step: load the existing data

    # first test if the file exists, and if not, use an empty score dictionary
    if not os.path.exists(class_file):
        scores = {}
    # otherwise populate the dictionary
    else:
        # open as read only, because we just want the data out of it
        with open(class_file, 'r') as f:
            # load contents of the json file "f" as object "scores"
            scores = json.load(f)

    # second step: update the data

    scores.setdefault(name, []).append(score)

    # third step: update the file

    # use 'w' when opening the file to overwrite all data within it
    with open(class_file, 'w') as f:
        # dump object "scores" within file "f"
        json.dump(scores, f)
```

Within this code, I used a trick to do insertion of the score in one line:

```
scores.setdefault(name, []).append(score)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
# if the user's "name" is not already in the dictionary
if name not in scores.keys():
    # add it as a new key containing an empty list
    scores[name] = []
# append the "score" to the list indexed by the user's "name"
scores[name].append(score)
```

Then the results within a file would look like:

```
{"John":[3,5,10],"Jane":[2],"Bob":[1,0,2]}
```

To make the output file more readable you can change the `json.dump` line into:

```
json.dump(scores, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

which will output:

```
{
    "Bob": [
        1,
        0,
        2
    ],
    "Jane": [
        2
    ],
    "John": [
        3,
        5,
        10
    ]
}
```

### How to run the QA?

Finally you want to create another function that handles the QA process, within which
you call the function we just defined

```
# add the following import at the start of your script if you're running python2 and not python3
from __future__ import print_function

def run_qa():
    print("What is your name?") # prints writing in brackets
    name = input().title() # Capitalizes the first letter of the word inputted

    print("What class are you in? (Enter 1, 2 or 3)") # asks the user to input a number

    while True:
        try:
            class_number = int(input()) # asks for an integer input from user
        except ValueError: 
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that, please try again") # print statement
            continue

        if class_number > 3: # if input is more than 3
            print("SORRY but that class isn't recognised, try again") # print statement
            continue
        else:
            break # break out of loop

    # prints writing in brackets and anything saved in the variables "name" and "class_number"
    print ("Hello, {} from class {} welcome to my quiz".format(name, class_number))

    score = 0  # sets the variable "score" to zero
    question = 0 # sets the variable "question" to zero

    while question < 3: # If questions (initially set to 0) is smaller than 10, carry out this function
        question += 1 # add one to the value of "question"
        maths = random.randint(1,3) # randomly generate a number from 1-3 and store as "maths"
        num1 = random.randint(1,10) # randomly generate an integer from 1-10 and store as "num1"
        num2 = random.randint(1,10) # randomly generate a second integer from 1-10 and store as "num2"
        if maths == 1: # if the number generated is 1
            print("{} + {} = ?".format(num1, num2)) # prints num1 + num2
            ans = num1 + num2 # sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 added to num2

        elif maths == 2: # if the number generated is 1
            print("{} * {} = ?".format(num1, num2)) # print num1 multiplied by num2
            ans = num1 * num2 # sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 multiplied by num2

        else: # else run this part of code
            print("{} - {} = ?".format(num1, num2)) # print num1 subtracted by num2
            ans = num1 - num2 # sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 subtracted by num2

        while True:
            try:
                # print a nice little prompt for the user to enter his answer
                print("> ", end="")
                user_ans = int(input()) # user inputs answer to question
                # if an exception is raised by "int()" the break is not being called
                # here you achieve the same as a single line, as you're doing in two
                # lines with your try/except/else clause, making your code more readable.
                break
            except ValueError: # runs when the user input is no an integer
                print ("SORRY but that answer isn't recognised, try again")


        if user_ans == ans:
            score += 1
            print("Well done, you are CORRECT")

        else:
            print("SORRY, you are INCORRECT") # print writing in brackets
            print("The correct answer was {}".format(ans))

    if score == 10: # run this part of code if "score" equals 10
         print("Fantastic {}, you got full marks!".format(name))# print statement and name
    elif score >= 6: # run this part of code if "score" is larger than or equal to 6
         print("Well done, there's some improvement to be done here, though {} you got {}/10".format(name, score))#  then print statement and score
    elif score <=5: # run this part of code if "score" is smaller than or equal to 5
         print("hmm, maybe some more practice would be beneficial, {}, you got {}/10".format(name, score)) # then print statement and score

    # return the results
    return class_number, name, score
```

Finally, to call your code, you just need to add the following at the end of your script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    class_number, name, score = run_qa()
    store_results(class_number, name, score):
```

the reason for the if statement is to make it possible to later include your code as
a module in another module without running it, which is considered good practice!

---

as another improvement I'd avoid repeating the same code several times to check input
from the user, but use a function instead:

```
def get_integer_input(maxval=None):
    while True:
        try:
            # print a nice prompt
            print("> ", eol="")
            i = int(input()) # asks for an integer input from user
            if maxval:
                if i >= maxval:
                    continue
                    print("Sorry, input shall be inferior than {}, try again".format(maxval))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that, please try again") # print statement

    return i
```

Then in your code you use it that way:

```
...
class_number = get_integer_input(maxval=3)
...
```

---

BTW, as an improvement, I'd actually split the `run_qa` in two functions: one that
generates the questions, and the other that does the interactive process.

so that you would do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    questions = generate_qa()
    class_number, name, score = run_qa(questions)
    store_results(class_number, name, score)
```

with `generate_qa()` being something like:

```
def generate_qa():
    questions = []
    while len(questions) < 3: # add a question until we have three generated
        op = random.randint(0,2) # randomly generate a number from 1-3 and store as "maths"
        num1 = random.randint(1,10) # randomly generate an integer from 1-10 and store as "num1"
        num2 = random.randint(1,10) # randomly generate a second integer from 1-10 and store as "num2"
        questions.append( (op, num1, num2) )
    return questions
```

and then:

```
def run_qa(questions):
    print("What is your name?") # prints writing in brackets
    name = input().title() # Capitalizes the first letter of the word inputted
    print("What class are you in? (Enter 1, 2 or 3)") # asks the user to input a number
    class_number = get_integer_input(maxval=3)

    # prints writing in brackets and anything saved in the variables "name" and "class_number"
    print ("Hello, {} from class {} welcome to my quiz".format(name, class_number))

    score = 0  # sets the variable "score" to zero

    for op, left, right in questions:
        if op == 0: # if the number generated is 0
            op("{} + {} = ?".format(left, right)) # prints 'left' + 'right'
            ans = left + right # sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 added to 'right'

        elif op == 1: # if the number generated is 1
            print("{} * {} = ?".format(left, right)) # print 'left' multiplied by 'right'
            ans = left * right # sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 multiplied by 'right'

        else: # the only possible value is: op == 2
            print("{} - {} = ?".format(left, right)) # print 'left' subtracted by 'right'
            ans = left - right # sets "ans" to equal the value of num1 subtracted by 'right'

        user_ans = get_integer_input()

        if user_ans == ans:
            score += 1
            print("Well done, you are CORRECT")

        else:
            print("SORRY, you are INCORRECT") # print writing in brackets
            print("The correct answer was {}".format(ans))

    if score == 10: # run this part of code if "score" equals 10
         print("Fantastic {}, you got full marks!".format(name))# print statement and name
    elif score >= 6: # run this part of code if "score" is larger than or equal to 6
         print("Well done, there's some improvement to be done here, though {} you got {}/10".format(name, score))#  then print statement and score
    elif score <=5: # run this part of code if "score" is smaller than or equal to 5
         print("hmm, maybe some more practise would be beneficial, {}, you got {}/10".format(name, score)) # then print statement and score

    return class_number, name, score
```

---

Finally, a last improvement that could be done to your code is to use a dict containing the operators:

```
import operator

operations = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '-': operator.sub
}
```

and then you'd simplify `run_qa` as follows:

```
def run_qa(questions):
    print("What is your name?") # prints writing in brackets
    name = input().title() # Capitalizes the first letter of the word inputted
    print("What class are you in? (Enter 1, 2 or 3)") # asks the user to input a number
    class_number = get_integer_input(maxval=3)

    # prints writing in brackets and anything saved in the variables "name" and "class_number"
    print ("Hello, {} from class {} welcome to my quiz".format(name, class_number))

    score = 0  # sets the variable "score" to zero

    for op, left, right in questions:
        # convert from index value into symbol (the "list()" is a needed trick for python3
        op = list(operations.keys())[op]
        print("{} {} {} = ?".format(left, op, right))

        # calculate the operation with operator 'op' using 'left' and 'right'
        ans = operations[op](left, right)

        user_ans = get_integer_input()

        if user_ans == ans:
            score += 1
            print("Well done, you are CORRECT")

        else:
            print("SORRY, you are INCORRECT") # print writing in brackets
            print("The correct answer was {}".format(ans))

    if score == 10: # run this part of code if "score" equals 10
         print("Fantastic {}, you got full marks!".format(name))# print statement and name
    elif score >= 6: # run this part of code if "score" is larger than or equal to 6
         print("Well done, there's some improvement to be done here, though {} you got {}/10".format(name, score))#  then print statement and score
    elif score <=5: # run this part of code if "score" is smaller than or equal to 5
         print("hmm, maybe some more practice would be beneficial, {}, you got {}/10".format(name, score)) # then print statement and score

    return class_number, name, score
```

*Nota Bene*: I have not tested my code locally, it's been live coding within the answer box
of stackoverflow, so there might be syntax errors and maybe minor bugs. The goal of
my answer is to emphasize what you're doing wrong and show you how to do better. So,
please do not take it "as is" to copy/paste, but read it through, understand what I'm
showing to you, and update your code with what I given you as an improvement.

---

Here's a full example I just tested:

```
# make the script both py2 and py3 compatible
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    input = raw_input

import operator
import random
import json
import os


def store_results(class_number, name, score):
    # this adds '.json' to the end of the file (therefore creating a json file)
    class_file = "{}.json".format(class_number)

    # first step: load the existing data

    # first test if the file exists, and if not, use an empty score dictionary
    if not os.path.exists(class_file):
        scores = {}
    # otherwise populate the dictionary
    else:
        # open as read only, because we just want the data out of it
        with open(class_file, 'r') as f:
            # load contents of the json file "f" as object "scores"
            scores = json.load(f)

    # second step: update the data

    scores.setdefault(name, []).append(score)

    # third step: update the file

    # use 'w' when opening the file to overwrite all data within it
    with open(class_file, 'w') as f:
        # dump object "scores" within file "f"
        json.dump(scores, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

def get_integer_input(maxval=None):
    while True:
        try:
            # print a nice prompt
            print("> ", end="")
            i = int(input()) # asks for an integer input from user
            if maxval:
                if i >= maxval:
                    continue
                    print("Sorry, input shall be inferior than {}, try again".format(maxval))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that, please try again") # print statement

    return i

operations = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '-': operator.sub
}

def generate_qa():
    questions = []
    while len(questions) < 3: # add a question until we have three generated
        op = random.randint(0,2) # randomly generate a number from 1-3 and store as "maths"
        num1 = random.randint(1,10) # randomly generate an integer from 1-10 and store as "num1"
        num2 = random.randint(1,10) # randomly generate a second integer from 1-10 and store as "num2"
        questions.append( (op, num1, num2) )
    return questions

def run_qa(questions):
    print("What is your name?") # prints writing in brackets
    name = input().title() # Capitalizes the first letter of the word inputted
    print("What class are you in? (Enter 1, 2 or 3)") # asks the user to input a number
    class_number = get_integer_input(maxval=3)

    # prints writing in brackets and anything saved in the variables "name" and "class_number"
    print ("Hello, {} from class {} welcome to my quiz".format(name, class_number))

    score = 0  # sets the variable "score" to zero

    for op, left, right in questions:
        # convert from index value into symbol (the "list()" is a needed trick for python3
        op = list(operations.keys())[op]
        print("{} {} {} = ?".format(left, op, right))
        # calculate the operation with operator 'op' using 'left' and 'right'
        ans = operations[op](left, right)

        user_ans = get_integer_input()

        if user_ans == ans:
            score += 1
            print("Well done, you are CORRECT")

        else:
            print("SORRY, you are INCORRECT") # print writing in brackets
            print("The correct answer was {}".format(ans))

    if score == 10: # run this part of code if "score" equals 10
            print("Fantastic {}, you got full marks!".format(name))# print statement and name
    elif score >= 6: # run this part of code if "score" is larger than or equal to 6
            print("Well done, there's some improvement to be done here, though {} you got {}/10".format(name, score))#  then print statement and score
    elif score <=5: # run this part of code if "score" is smaller than or equal to 5
            print("hmm, maybe some more practise would be beneficial, {}, you got {}/10".format(name, score)) # then print statement and score

    return class_number, name, score

if __name__ == "__main__":
    questions = generate_qa()
    class_number, name, score = run_qa(questions)
    store_results(class_number, name, score)
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much! I have implemented this step by step, however i get a "syntax error" from this line and so it won't run -                                               def store_results(class_number, name, score):

Comment: Make sure you do not mess up indentation.

Comment: One of the advantages of splitting the code into functions is that if you want to replace the random generated questions with a file containing manually written questions, you easily can. Also you could replace the `run_qa` function to create and expose a web page to get and answer the questions… ☺

Comment: Thank you but I am a bit confused now because I am almost positive the indentations are correct, and If they weren't then the error message would be "expected indentation block" rather than "syntax error" which Is what I am greeted with.

Comment: try copy pasting the last scripted code in a `script.py` file and run it on the command line using `python script.py` (or `python3 script.py`)

Comment: I am very new to this, what will that do? How do I run it on the command line? Sorry for being such a pain :(

Comment: well, you create a new file called `script.py` and then from the command line, you call `python script.py` or `python3 script.py` (if you're using windows first change the directory to where you have `python.exe`, I'm not a windows user so I cannot help you more on that)

Comment: Woohoo I found the error thank you, however when I run the code it works as it did before, except nothing changes within the text document, No scores are added or anything it just stays blank.